# Tumblr show random photo post

Tags: post, random, tumblr, photo

I've recently moved from posts with html imgs tags to pure photo post. Because reblogged imgs tags will not show automatically.

The problem is now that the random function "/random" don't show the photo postings only the text postings.

Somebody have a clue?

Comment: Emm, the [tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) doesn't appear to list /random

Comment: Its a Tumblr feature. Visit `http://xxx.tumblr.com/random` will give the visitor a random post. It won't be covered by the API.

Comment: Yes exactly but it works only with posts not with img posts.

Comment: The Tumblr feature `/random` works on all kinds of Tumblr posts. You probably have a lot of posts and it had picked the text posts so far. I am using random in my tumblr blog and it shows my image posts.